# Android notifications different icon for status bar and notification body

Tags: android, push-notification, statusbar, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have a notification of battery level. I want to make different icon in status bar and notifications center. In status bar: number (2 digits). In body: my app icon.
How can I do that? The app icon is also in the status bar, how can I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your code looks like right now but I'd do something like this:

```
Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(context)
.setContentTitle("title")
.setContentText("content")
.setAutoCancel(true)
.setLargeIcon(R.drawable.large_icon)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
.setTicker("ticker text");
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.notify(100, nb.build());
```

Note the `setLargeIcon()` and `setSmallIcon()`. The icon you want to show in the 'ticker' should be set in `setSmallIcon()` and for what you have called the 'notification centre', you should use `setLargeIcon()`. That should work.